# Unresolved reference: Source - org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.source

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, maven, spring-cloud-stream

I am updating some project libraries because of vulnerabilities and after this updates I can't meke this import work:

`import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Source` 
("Source" is red in InteliJ)

Error message is: "Unsolved reference: Source".

I have red that it is part of this dependendy:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId> org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
 <artifactId> spring-cloud-stream </artifactId>
 <version>4.0.4
</dependency>
```

But this is a Kotlin (I'm not so familiar with Kotlin :-/) project, so I found I should use this?

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Unfortunately both of this dependencies do not fix this (when I do: mvn clean install -U).

I'll be glad for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the annotation-based programming model which included classes such as `StreamListener, Source, EnableBinding` etc. . . has long (~5 years) been deprecated and removed from the code base.
We have switched to a more robust functional model - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_producing_and_consuming_messages